# angularJsのコントローラに値を追加したい

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJSのループとフィルターを使って、テーブルを出力しています。
そのテーブルに表示後から値を追加したいのですが、どのように追加すればいいかわかりません。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', [])
    app.controller('myController', function() {
      this.members = [
        { name: 'Toyota', score:20298 },
        { name: 'Honda', score:20302 },
        { name: 'Suzuki', score:20303 }
      ];
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#button_id').click(function(){
          $('#table_id tr:last').after('<tr><td>masao</td><td>00009</td></tr>');
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" id="area">
  <section class="list1">
    <table border="1" id="table_id">
      <tr ng-repeat="member in myCtrl.members|filter:searchText">
        <td>{{member.name}} </td><td>{{member.score}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
</div>
<button id="button_id" type="button">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

上記のサンプルではjQueryを使い強引に値["masao",00009]を追加していますが、当然これではフィルタはかからないし、jQueryは使いたく無いのですが、どのようにangularjsで書けばいいかわかりません。
ご存知の方いましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

意図に合致しているか分かりませんが、以下で同様なことができるかと思います。見当違いでしたら申し訳ございません。少しでもご参考になれば幸いです。

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', [])
    app.controller('myController', function() {
      this.members = [
        { name: 'Toyota', score:20298 },
        { name: 'Honda', score:20302 },
        { name: 'Suzuki', score:20303 }
      ];
      <!-- #####追加##### -->
      this.click = function(){
      this.members.push({name:'masao',score:00009});
      };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" id="area">
  <section class="list1">
    <table border="1" id="table_id">
      <tr ng-repeat="member in myCtrl.members|filter:searchText">
        <td>{{member.name}} </td><td>{{member.score}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
<!-- #####ng-clickを追加##### -->
 <button id="button_id" type="button" ng-click="myCtrl.click()">button</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```